# Coordinate ring $\mathcal O(V)$ is field iff $V$ contains just a point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Since I have no enough point to comment. I am referring this post's answer:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1007134/1015445

Everything is ok but why

> But if $k[V]=k$ these functions on $V$ cannot separate two points, so that $V$ contains only one point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k[V]=k$ means that the functions on this variety $V$ are exactly the constant functions. A set of functions $A$ on a space $X$ separates points if for all pairs of distinct points $x,y\in X$, there exists $f\in A$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$. The constant functions on $V$ do not separate points because given a pair of distinct points $x$ and $y$, any constant function takes the same value on both points.